# Reorganizing multidimensional arrays based on multiple value characteristics in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble organizing this data the way I would like it to. On my pages, a few things happen that I know work...

1. Some PHP spits out a multidimensional associative array. The top level of this array is an array of regions. Each region is an array of timezones.
2. Some more PHP creates a second multidimensional associative array. The top level of this array is an array of regions. Each region is an array of UTC offsets.
3. Both arrays are generated in the same order from the same data. This means that `$offsets["region"][0]` will have be based on the same timezone as `$timezones["region"][0]`.
4. Both arrays are encoded into JSON and passed to my JavaScript.

I have the following JavaScript code...

```
var tempCurrentTimezoneArray = timezoneArray[ $("select[name='region_selector']").val() ];
  var tempCurrentOffsetArray = timezoneOffsetArray[ $("select[name='region_selector']").val() ];
  var groupedTimezones = {};
  var groupedOffsets = {};
  for (counter = 0; counter < tempCurrentOffsetArray.length; counter++) { 
    significantOffset = tempCurrentOffsetArray[counter].substr(tempCurrentOffsetArray[counter].length - 2);
    if (!(significantOffset in groupedTimezones)) {
      groupedTimezones[significantOffset] = [];
      groupedOffsets[significantOffset] = [];
    }
    groupedTimezones[significantOffset].push(tempCurrentTimezoneArray[counter]);
    groupedOffsets[significantOffset].push(tempCurrentOffsetArray[counter]);    
  }
  var offsetArray = [];
  for (var property in groupedTimezones) {
    if (!groupedTimezones.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        continue;
    }
    groupedTimezones[property].sort();
    groupedOffsets[property].sort();
    offsetArray.push(parseInt(property));
  }
  offsetArray.sort();
  var currentTimezoneArray = [];
  var currentOffsetArray = [];
  for (counter = 0; counter < offsetArray.length; counter++) {
    currentTimezoneArray = currentTimezoneArray.concat(groupedTimezones[offsetArray[counter]]);
    currentOffsetArray = currentOffsetArray.concat(groupedOffsets[offsetArray[counter]]);
  }
```

In the top two lines I remove all of the timezone data not pertaining to the region selected on the page. This means that I am left with 2 single-dimensional arrays. Any given index of either array relates directly to the other array. I.E....

`tempCurrentOffsetArray[0]` is the UTC offset of the timezone found at `tempCurrentTimezoneArray[0]`.

The rest of this code is intended to complete the following tasks...

1. Group timezones and offsets by their UTC offset.
2. Organize each offset group in alphabetical order.
3. Create two arrays where values are organized first by UTC offset and second by alphabetical order.

The problem I'm having is that on some regions I receive almost perfect listings,and on others I receive some listings with a seemingly random number of undefined values, and I'm not sure why. Can anyone identify the syntactical or logical errors in my code?

JSON of `tempCurrentTimezoneArray` input data [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nLgjqo0pdcvMLxnz57RdVt49LwpkY4sLR_pYDr6rnTE/edit?usp=sharing)

JSON of `tempCurrentOffsetArray` input data [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CFYsEh7nZBf1IG7lXVM3A_V5BIsBTFIXApZzYtxFbJ4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: please add some example of your data.

Comment: @NinaScholz Added links to JSON encoded versions of the actual data passed to this script.

Comment: I ran your code using the sample data but I can not see any undefined values in the resultant arrays. I can see a possible wrong mapping where offset of 0.5 is handled, but thats it. Can you specify exactly which offsets or regions you are seeing the undefined values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You think still too complicated. It is a mess to keep these two Arrays in sync, better use one Array with objects.

```
var region_selector = $("select[name='region_selector']").val();
var tempCurrentTimezoneArray = timezoneArray[ region_selector ];
var tempCurrentOffsetArray = timezoneOffsetArray[ region_selector ];

//consolidate the Arrays
var data = [];  //create a new Array `data`
for(var i = tempCurrentOffsetArray.length; i--; ){
    //write into Array `data` at index `i` an object, containing these properties: 
    //`timezone`, `offset` and `offsetValue`, and their respective values
    data[i] = {
        timezone: tempCurrentTimezoneArray[i],
        offset: tempCurrentOffsetArray[i],
        //the + at the beginning converts the value behind that into a Number, like parseFloat() would do
        offsetValue: +tempCurrentOffsetArray[i].match(/^GMT([+-]\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/)[1]
    }
}

//sorter-function for data to sort the values by offsetValue ASC first, then by timezone ASC
function sortedByOffset(a, b){
    return a.offsetValue - b.offsetValue || a.timezone.localeCompare(b.timezone);
}

//you should do this as late as possible, usually after the filtering
data.sort(sortedByOffset);
```

If you insist on the two output-Arrays

```
var currentTimezoneArray = data.map(d => d.timezone);
var currentOffsetArray = data.map(d => d.offset);
```

otherwise this is imo more flexible

```
//utilities to fetch a property off the object
var getTimezone = d => d.timezone;
//aka function getTimezone(d){ return d.timezone }
var getOffset = d => d.offset;
//aka function getOffset(d){ return d.offset }

//example usages:
data.filter(d => d.offset === "GMT-5").map( getTimezone );
data.filter(d => d.offsetValue >= -2 && d.offsetValue <= -5 ).map( getOffset );
```

taking the first example; thinking in terms of a SQL-statement this would be

```
SELECT timezone FROM data WHERE offset = "GMT-5"
```

get me the timezone-values for each entry where the offset is GMT-5

you start with an Array containsing all values `data` then you get the subset you are interested in (in this case every entry, with the offset "GMT-5") by filtering.

Now you have an Array containing all values you are intersted in, but still the whole objects; like a `SELECT * FROM ...`

the `map()` function calls the function `getTimezone()` on every entry in this subset and returns another Array containing only the timezone-values.

The second example defines a range for the filter (every entry from GMT-2 to and including GMT-5 and every GMT in between) and returns for these entries the offset-protperty.

Comment: I'm pretty new to JavaScript. Could you please add a little bit more of an explanation for the logic and functions you're using to achieve this result?

Comment: You could even include the "region" into the data-objects, and make this just another filter; just as a sidenote. **What in particular do you need explained?** the logic is simple: one big Array containing an Object for each row (index) and properties for each column, like you would think of an Excel-table. then adding filter, sort by whatever, and map the data you actually want; maybe one column (like the timezone or the offset), maybe you want to process this value somehow, like concatenating the timezone and offset into one String, ...

Comment: the filtering is where I'm getting a little bit confused. All of the other functions I can look up on my own, but I can't seem to find an answer online as to what the meaning of "=>" is in this case.

Comment: or do you get screwed over the lambda-expressions, or assigning functions to variables or passing them to other functions? Well, lambdas: `d => d.timezone` for example is simply a  shorthand for `function(d){ return d.timezone }` a function expecting an Object `d` and returning the property `timezone` of this object. And the other part, well yes, you can create a reference to a function and pass it around like any other Value in JS

Comment: @Allenph, `d => d.offset === "GMT-5"` for example is simply a shorthand for `function(d){ return d.offset === "GMT-5" }` this function is called on every entry of the data-Array and returns a new Array, containing all the Entries where the filter-function returned a truthy value. (0, NaN, empty-string, null, undefined, false) are falsy values (resolve to false; in conditions for example), every other value is truthy

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't seem to help me much. Take your first example from the example usages. Your calling a method that I don't see defined anywhere. I also don't see what's going on in the first set of parentheses. Are you acquiring a boolean? I'm also unsure why you're using `.map()` which seems to be a function used to acquire the square roots of array values. None of this seems to have any bearing on what the intended function is. Sorry if I'm just blatantly missing something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108695/discussion-between-thomas-and-allenph).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue with my code. There were actually three issues the first being on line 6. After looking over the data one more time I realized that some of the values had offsets that were floating point integers or had more than two significant digits. The new line 6 is...

```
significantOffset = tempCurrentOffsetArray[counter].replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
```

The second issue with my code also had to do with parsing floating integers. On line 21 we need to use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. The new line 21 is...

```
offsetArray.push(parseFloat(property));
```

The third issue lies on line 23. `sort()` needs to be told how to sort the integers. This is the new line 23...

```
offsetArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

The final code looks like this...

```
var tempCurrentTimezoneArray = timezoneArray[ $("select[name='region_selector']").val() ];
    var tempCurrentOffsetArray = timezoneOffsetArray[ $("select[name='region_selector']").val() ];
    var groupedTimezones = {};
    var groupedOffsets = {};
    for (counter = 0; counter < tempCurrentOffsetArray.length; counter++) { 
      significantOffset = tempCurrentOffsetArray[counter].replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
      if (!(significantOffset in groupedTimezones)) {
    groupedTimezones[significantOffset] = [];
    groupedOffsets[significantOffset] = [];
      }
      groupedTimezones[significantOffset].push(tempCurrentTimezoneArray[counter]);
      groupedOffsets[significantOffset].push(tempCurrentOffsetArray[counter]);    
    }
    var offsetArray = [];
    for (var property in groupedTimezones) {
      if (!groupedTimezones.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      continue;
      }
      groupedTimezones[property].sort();
      groupedOffsets[property].sort();
      offsetArray.push(parseFloat(property));
    }
    offsetArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    var currentTimezoneArray = [];
    var currentOffsetArray = [];
    for (counter = 0; counter < offsetArray.length; counter++) {
      currentTimezoneArray = currentTimezoneArray.concat(groupedTimezones[offsetArray[counter]]);
      currentOffsetArray = currentOffsetArray.concat(groupedOffsets[offsetArray[counter]]);
    }
```